# Android: Children of gridview are null when keyboard opens and covers grid

Tags: android, gridview, keyboard, children

I have a gridview that is made of of 31 cells. A user can select any combination of cells and then click on a button to save their selections. Once they click the save button a dialog box appears and asks them what they want to do next. Within this dialog is a edit text view. When the user clicks inside the edit text box the keyboard appears. When this happens only 21 of the 31 cells are visible on the screen and when I try to call the getChildrenCount() method of GridView class I only see 21 children. Can someone explain why this happens and what I can do to eliminate this issue? I have attached images in hopes that clarifies the issue. Below I have pasted a snippet of code where I am trying to get the child count of the gridview.

```
protected Set<String> getSelectedFrequencies() {
    Set<String> selectedFrequencies = new HashSet<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < gridView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) gridView.getChildAt(i);
        for(int k = 0; k < gridChild.getChildCount(); k++) {
            if( gridChild.getChildAt(k) instanceof Button ) {
                if(gridChild.getChildAt(k).isSelected()) {
                    selectedFrequencies.add(gridChild.getChildAt(k).getTag().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return selectedFrequencies;
}
```

There is nothing really special about the code.[image: Image capture of GridView before dialog appears and keyboard pops up][image: Image capture of GridView when keyboard pops up]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a softInputMode of pan or resize?  With pan that will never happen.  With resize, it could be that only 21 fit on screen, so the gridView creates only 21 children and does view swapping when you scroll.  In case you didn't know, listview and gridview only create as many views as are needed to fit on the screen.  When you scroll it just loads data for the new positions into the existing views.